# How do I both output stdout and stderr and write them into a file?

Tags: bash, awk, stdout, ping, stderr

I basically want to write my ping statistics into a file. So far, I accomplished this with `ping adress | awk '{ print strftime("[%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S]"), $0}' > textfile` but it would be more handy to be able to look at the output without having to interrupt the process before.
I am also aware that this command does not write stderr into my textfile. I came up with that part while writing this question.

The command or script should basically behave like this:

`$ command > textfile
[15.08.2017 00:17:07] PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
[15.08.2017 00:17:07] 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=44 time=11.5 ms
[15.08.2017 00:17:08] 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=44 time=11.5 ms
^C
$ cat textfile
[15.08.2017 00:17:07] PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
[15.08.2017 00:17:07] 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=44 time=11.5 ms
[15.08.2017 00:17:08] 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=44 time=11.5 ms`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. In general it is expected here to offer an example of the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your command to this:

```
ping address 2>&1 | awk '{ print strftime("[%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S]"), $0}' | tee textfile
```

`2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout which goes to `awk`. `tee` allows you to have both the output on your screen and in the file you specified.

You may be annoyed by `awk` buffering its output which will be displayed by blocks. Then use either:

```
awk '{ print strftime("[%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S]"), $0; fflush()}'
```

or:

```
stdbuf -oL awk '{ print strftime("[%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S]"), $0}'
```

Comment: Strangely, the command does not output anything while both `ping address 2>&1 | awk '{ print strftime("[%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S]"), $0}'` and `ping adress 2>&1 | tee textfile` work just fine. I may also add that I am using zsh

Comment: awk's output may be buffered. Try one of the two alternatives I gave at the end of my answer.